# Bison - additional parameter to a push and pure parser

Tags: c, parsing, grammar, bison, parser-generator

How can I pass one aditional parameter (not the token minor of type `YYSTYPE`) to the `yypush_parse()` function?

The parser is indeed reentrant, but this one aditional variable is crucial for the thread-safety of the application I need to integrate my parser in (it's a PHP extension, so we're talking about [TSRM](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1021)).

I cannot just get rid of that parameter because inside the action code I'm going to call functions which will generate an AST in a userland-accessible form.

I've tried to hack around `YYPUSH_DECLS` and it works as far as declaring the function is concerned, BUT a few thousand LOCs down comes the implementation of `yypush_parse`, and I can't see any way to overwrite the function signature where the implementation of `yypush_parse` starts.

`YYPARSE_PARAM` is only used when the parser is not a push one (as far as I can tell), but in my case I NEED it be push because of the things I have to do in the processing loop, after lexing and prior to adding a new token to the parsing stack.

So I am wondering if there's a `%directive` or something that may help.

On the other side, I really think `YYPARSE_PARAM` should be used as far as it's defined, no matter what type of parser it is. It's a pity it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%parse-param`. `YYPARSE_PARAM` is deprecated and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Sadly, `%parse-param` is for the `yyparse()` function, not `yypush_parse()`.

Comment: OK: let's revise my comment - sadly, the documentation does not mention that `%parse-param` can be used with `yypush_parse()`, AFAICS.  Your empirical evidence suggests that it can be used; we should perhaps get a note to the Bison team that this bit is missing from the documentation.